# python os.getcwd() returns empty string

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell

I have a shell on a directory

```
bash-4.1$ pwd
/x/dev/local_base
```

but when i run a python script

```
cur_dir = os.getcwd()
print "cur dir %s" % cur_dir
```

and it returns an empty string

I've tried

```
p = subprocess.Popen("/bin/pwd", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

and it returns empty as well

but `pwd` on the shell shows current directory (/x/dev/local_base)

this only happens when i leave the shell for a long time (few hours). if i cd back to the directory, it works fine.

I think the directory is getting snapshotted off and being recreated in the background.

Any suggestions on how to get current working dir?

PS  these work fine

```
p = subprocess.Popen("ls", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

and

```
os.listdir('.')
```

when i tried `os.path.abspath` on one of the files returned from `listdir`, it only shows relative path i.e. if listdir returns a file name `README`, it returns `README`, not `/x/dev/local_base/README`

Comment: You might be missing permission? That's at least what the cwd documentation say's when it returns 0

Comment: @user1767754 what do you mean by missing permission? i have to chown or something?

Comment: Do you have read and examination permissions on the cwd?

Comment: @Prune yes, i can pwd as myself on shell and python script is running as myself